# Переменные окружения Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu

Объявил переменную окружения `TEST=HELLO WORLD!`. После закрытия консоли она не доступна, как ее сохранить на постоянной основе?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Не сохраняются переменные XUBUNTU](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/386629/%d0%9d%d0%b5-%d1%81%d0%be%d1%85%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d1%8f%d1%8e%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-xubuntu)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вы хотите, чтобы эта переменная была не только в **текущей** консоли, но и учитывалась в программах, то вам надо прописать её в .bashrc не как: TEST=HELLO WORLD!, а export TEST=HELLO WORLD!, тогда она будет экспортироваться не только в текущий шелл, но и во все остальные.Это легко проверить:

```
cat 1.sh #!/bin/bashecho $TEST$ TEST=HELLO$ ./1.sh
```

Ничего нет.

```
$ export TEST=HELLO./1.sh HELLO
```

Появилось слово HELLO.

Так же, если вам интересно, почитайте про различия .profile, .bashrc, .bash_profile, .login.

Comment: @aza1io1.sh  - это какой то системный файл ?Вот что мне выдает после применения команды export root@Server:~# export TEST=HELLO ./1.sh-bash: export: `./1.sh': неправильный идентификатор

Comment: @zsiteru я его создал сам.Написал в него:\#!/bin/bashecho $TESTвыполнил chmod +x 1.sh, чтобы он стал запускаемым.

Answer (score 1):

пропишите ее в ~/.bashrc

Answer (score 0):

Если хочешь, чтобы новая перменная была глобальной и была всегда доступна всем приложениям, то ее можно прописать в /etc/environment