# Не сохраняются переменные XUBUNTU

Tags: linux

Не сохраняются переменные. Делаю так

```
export CATALINA_HOME="/opt..."
```

И все хорошо, но только до перезагрузки компьютера. После перезагрузки переменных не оказывается. В чем дело?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Чтобы установить переменную окружения для всей системы на Ubuntu, можно добавить файл `/etc/profile.d/tomcat.sh` и записать в него:

```
export CATALINA_HOME="/opt..."
```

Если только для одного пользователя хочется изменить переменную окружения, то можно использовать `~/.profile`.

Оба файла исполняются (source) при заходе пользователя (login). См. [EnvironmentVariables](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables).

Точные правила, когда какие файлы читаются, зависят от shell (bash, zsh, sh), например, [bash не читает `~/.profile` при логине, если `~/.bash_profile` или `~/.bash_login` файлы существуют](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Bash-Startup-Files). Детали также могут зависеть от графической оболочки, версии дистрибутива.

При использовании `bash`, `~/.bashrc` файл читается либо прямо (interactive shell), либо косвенно через `*profile` файлы (login shell).

Я видел, как [люди составляли целые диаграммы](http://blog.flowblok.id.au/2013-02/shell-startup-scripts.html), которые показывали, какие файлы когда читаются при запуске и существуют пакеты, которые пытаются нормализовать процесс и скрыть отличия. Это может улучшить переносимость за счёт повышения хрупкости и сложности решения.

Простой и надёжной альтернативой является создание скрипта-обёртки, который содержит необходимые для запуска программы переменные окружения и вызывает саму программу.

Comment: Клевый ответ +1

Answer (score 1):

Запишите переменки в глобальную область `/etc/environment` (может отличаться от вида ОС).
Либо в конфигуратор шела (к примеру, в файл `~/.bashrc`).

Comment: Если б еще подсказали, как это сделать... в конфигурацию шела.

Comment: `/etc/environment` - это файл, в нем нужно прописать экспорты. Он читается при загрузке системы.  `~/.bashrc` читается при загрузке юзера.

Comment: @Bimawa, не должно быть там никаких экспортов, насколько понимаю, там вообще не совсем bash-синтаксис. Сломать его на раз-два, а вот починить систему после того, как PATH упал - дело веселое.

Comment: ну Linux  поломать много ума не надо :)
Еще можно вот в этом файле прописать: ~/.profile

Answer (score 1):

Читайте [The Bash Shell Startup Files](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/~krejzi/kde5/postlfs/profile.html).

Куда прописывать  CATALINA_HOME=... (в /etc/profile или ~/.bashrc) зависит от того, как предполагается использовать tomcat на этом компе.

[Тут один из примеров](http://www.mulesoft.com/tcat/tomcat-linux)