# Python 3 и русские символы: print('Всем привет!') ведёт к UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode... ошибке

Tags: python, linux, кодировка, python-3.x

Пишу обычную программу `print('Всем привет!')` и запускаю python3.4 main.py, а в ответ:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "main.py", line 1, in 
>       print('\u0412\u0441\u0435\u043c \u043f\u0440\u0438\u0432\u0435\u0442!')
>   UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec
>   can't encode characters in position
>   0-3: ordinal not in range(128)

Система:

> webapp: ~/Applications $ uname -a
>   Linux webapp 3.13.0-29-generic
>
> 53-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jun 4 21:00:20 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В начале файла добавьте:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# vim:fileencoding=utf-8
```

Comment: Почему так происходит?

Comment: Укажите Вашему python в конфигурационном файле, что, кроме других кодировок, существует utf-8.

Comment: @thecrydemon, не понимаю: python3.4 -c 'import sys; print(sys.getdefaultencoding())' дает utf-8

Comment: Это не связано с тем, что в системе нет русского языка?

Comment: Решение написано тут: http://www.truevds.ru/labs/archives/80

Comment: ошибка в вопросе не имеет отношения к кодировке исходного кода (utf-8 является кодировкой по умолчанию в Python 3, и сообщение об ошибке явно показывает, что строка `'\u0412\u0441...'` уже является Юникодным текстом.

Answer (score 13):

Питон использует кодировку терминала для печати, которая не имеет никакого отношения к `sys.getdefaultencoding()`.

Иногда переменные окружения, определяющие язык, такие как `LANGUAGE`, `LC_ALL`,`LC_CTYPE`, `LANG` могут быть  не установлены, например, в окружении используемом ssh, upstart, Salt, mod_wsgi, crontab, etc. В этом случае используется C (POSIX) локаль, которая использует ascii кодировку, что приводит к `UnicodeEncodeError` ошибке, т.к. русские буквы не представимы в ascii. В Python 3.7, реализована [PEP 540: Forced UTF-8 Runtime Mode](https://docs.python.org/dev/whatsnew/3.7.html#whatsnew37-pep540): utf-8 режим включается по умолчанию для "C" локали.

Серверные варианты Linux могут использовать C локаль по умолчанию. Настольные инсталяции дитрибутивов Linux обычно имеют utf-8 локаль.

Ошибка в вопросе связана с Питон багом: [Python 3 raises Unicode errors with the C locale](http://bugs.python.org/issue19846). Разработчики решили следовать ascii кодировке из C локали, даже если это ошибка в подавляющем большинстве случаев, но в Python 3.7 ситуация может улучшится в поведении по умолчанию, см. [PEP 538 -- Coercing the legacy C locale to a UTF-8 based locale](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0538/).

Чтобы временно изменить используемую кодировку можно определить `PYTHONIOENCODING`:

```
$ PYTHONIOENCODING=utf-8 python your-script.py
```

В качестве более постоянного решения, нужно убедиться что используется utf-8 локаль в окружении, которое запускает python. Не обязательно русскую локаль устанавливать, чтобы напечатать русский текст. В этом достоинство Юникода, что можно работать с многими языками одновременно. Например, существует `C.UTF-8` локаль.

Если `locale -a` не показывает ни одной utf-8 локали, то на Debian системах  следует установить locales пакет и выбрать utf-8 локаль для использования:

```
root# aptitude install locales
root# dpkg-reconfigure locales
```

Индивидульно, каждый пользователь может настроить переменные окружения (см. [Не сохраняются переменные XUBUNTU](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/386629/linux-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%85%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%8F%D1%8E%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-xubuntu) ), например:

```
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
```

Используется первая доступная переменная из списка: `LC_ALL`, `LC_CTYPE`, `LANG`.

Может потребоваться сконфигурировать для работы с utf-8 индивидуальные программы, такие как xterm, Gnome Terminal, screen, отдельно.