# Сломанная кодировка при выводе в Python 2.7

Tags: python, кодировка, python-2.x

Имеется сценарий, когда я его выполняю, вместо русских символов появляется:

```
 X  РџРѕР»СѓС‡РµРЅРѕ: None | РћР¶РёРґР°Р»РѕСЃСЊ: '\xd0\xad\xd1\x82\xd0\xbe\xd1\x82 \xd1\x84\xd0\xb8\xd0\xbb\xd1\x8c\xd0\xbc \xd1\x85\xd0\xbe\xd1\x80\xd0\xbe\xd1\x88'.
```

Гугл предложил решение проблемы путем добавления в начало файла строк:

```
  #  -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
  from __future__ import unicode_literals
```

Но в таком случае появляется вывод:

```
u'\u042d\u0442\u043e\u0442 \u0444\u0438\u043b\u044c\u043c \u0445\u043e\u0440\u043e\u0448'
```

Т.е добавляется префикс "u",но на итог это почти никак не влияет. 
Пробовал менять кодировку файла. Не помогает. Понимаю, вопрос глупый и решается, скорей всего, элементарно.

Код:

```
def main():
    test(donuts(4), 'Количество : 4')
    test(donuts(9), 'Количество : 9')
```

Код функции:

```
 def donuts(count):+
    if count<10:
        rezult = 'Количество: {}'.format(count)
    else:
        rezult = 'Количество: много'

    return rezult
```

Функция `test`:

```
def test(got, expected):
    if got == expected:
        prefix = ' OK '
    else:
        prefix = '  X '
    print('%s Получено: %s | Ожидалось: %s' % (prefix, repr(got), repr(expected)))
```

Проблема одна и та же в Ubuntu и Windows. В данный момент пытаюсь бороться в Windows XP

Comment: Внутри функции test просто print() ? И ещё какая ОС? [вот тут](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/141035) был похожий вопрос для windows.

Comment: код функции test добавил, проблема и в убунту и в винде

Comment: Если убрать repr(), то у меня строка выводится полностью на русском.

Comment: Спасибо, в test я не пытался искать проблему

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Кракозябы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/414060/23044) вы видите потому что используете байты, а не Unicode для текста, что ведёт к выводу текста в неправильной кодировке (текст закодированный в utf-8 выводится в Виндовой кодировке):

```
>>> u'Получено'.encode('utf-8').decode('cp1251')
'РџРѕР»СѓС‡РµРЅРѕ'
```

Не используйте байты, **используйте Unicode для представления текста**.

`from __future__ import unicode_literals` заставляет `'abc'` строковые константы создавать Unicode строки на Питоне 2 (их поведение из Питона 3). В противном случае, используйте `u''` префикс, чтобы текст в виде констант в коде задавать.

---

`u'\u042d\u0442\u043e'` появляется потому что вы вызываете `repr()` функцию, которая возвращает текстовое представление объекта. Задача `repr()` функции получить однозначное представление объекта, например, для отладки, тестов. Идеально, когда `eval(repr(obj)) == obj`.

В общем случае, чтобы напечатать Юникодную строчку в Питоне, уберите `repr()`:

```
>>> print(u'\u042d\u0442\u043e')
Это
```

Если печатаемые символы поддерживаются в текущем окружении (кодировка консоли на Винде, [правильная локаль в *nix](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/387387/23044)), то этого достаточно. Если вывод текста перенаправлен в Питоне 2 или хочется произвольные символы печатать на Windows, даже те которые не поддерживаются OEM codepage такой как cp866, то [настройте `PYTHONIOENCODING`, если вывод перенаправлен в файл, pipe или установите `win-unicode-console` пакет, чтобы в Windows консоль показывать любые (BMP) символы (если правильный шрифт настроен)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/141035/23044).

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так

```
>>> print('\xd0\xad\xd1\x82\xd0\xbe\xd1\x82 \xd1\x84\xd0\xb8\xd0\xbb\xd1\x8c\xd0\xbc \xd1\x85\xd0\xbe\xd1\x80\xd0\xbe\xd1\x88'.decode('utf-8'))
Этот фильм хорош
```

Полезную информацию, также можете найти [здесь](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html), [здесь](http://local.joelonsoftware.com/wiki/%D0%90%D0%B1%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%9C%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D1%83%D0%BC,_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B4%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BA_%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D0%9E%D0%B1%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%8F%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE_%D0%94%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD_%D0%97%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C_%D0%BE_Unicode_%D0%B8_%D0%9D%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%85_%D0%A1%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2), [здесь](https://habrahabr.ru/post/135913/) и [здесь](http://prgssr.ru/development/unicode-v-vebe-vvedenie-dlya-nachinayushih.html)

Comment: нет смысла текст в нечитаемых байтовых строках задавать, лучше сразу Юникодную константу использовать: `u'Этот фильм хорош'` (или если OP использует `from __future__ import unicode_literals`, то просто `'Этот фильм хорош'`—`.decode('utf-8')` вариант ломается в этом случае).