# Python. Перевести байт-код в человекочитаемый вид в элементе списка

Tags: python, строки

Изначально имеется строка

```
 >>> string = '50.6,383,149,1.9,786, 4 -4, [Ne]3s²3p², DIA,5.43'
```

которая была разбита в лист по разделителю ","

```
>>> print(re.split(r',', string))
['50.6', '383', '149', '1.9', '786', ' 4 -4', ' [Ne]3s\xc2\xb23p\xc2\xb2', ' DIA', '5.43']
```

Элемент [Ne]3s²3p² был переведен в байт код '[Ne]3s\xc2\xb23p\xc2\xb2'.

Его можно успешно принтовать в человеческом виде

```
>>> print('[Ne]3s\xc2\xb23p\xc2\xb2'.decode('utf-8'))
[Ne]3s²3p²
```

А вот возможно перевести его в человекочитаемый вид и вписать обратно в список?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

У вас не байт-код (содержимое `*.pyc` файлов), а просто текстовое представление объекта типа `str` в Питоне, возвращаемое функцией `repr()`.

Вы его видите, потому что по умолчанию при печати списка в Питоне вызывается `repr()` для каждого элемента списка.

Если вы хотите другой результат, то форматируйте список, возвращаемый функцией `re.split()` самостоятельно, например, чтобы напечатать каждый элемент списка на отдельной строчке:

```
for элемент in ваш_список:
    print(элемент)
```

---

Дополнительно, результат намекает что вы используете Питон  2. В этом случае, либо добавьте на самом верху `from __future__ import unicode_literals` или явно используйте `u""` префикс, чтобы создать Юникодную строчку (из константы в исходном коде) вместо использования байт, иначе вы [можете кракозябы получить при печати](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/453220/23044).

Comment: Добавил пояснение к вопросу, и попробовал решение предложенное вами, оно дает ошибку

Comment: @while1pass: я ответил на вопрос как он у вас стоял. Сейчас у вас уже другой вопрос—не меняйте вопрос, если это делает неверными уже опубликованные ответы. Задайте отдельный вопрос с проблемой, которая у вас уже действительно есть (если ввод в файле, то надо так и говорить в вопросе—как прочитать Юникод из файла, отличается от того как в исходном коде создать Юникодную строчку, с помощью строковой константы такой как `u'abc'`). Показывайте только код, который вы действительно используете (конечно, [для вопроса его нужно сократить](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve))

Comment: новый вопрос создал [здесь](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/521598/python-postgresql-csv-%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8B-%D1%81-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B5-csv-%D0%B2-%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%83-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-pos)