# Проблемы с кодировкой при импорте CSV в базу данных PostgreSQL

Tags: python, postgresql, python-2.x, csv

Изначально имеется CSV-файл с текстовыми данными, которые я вставляю в базу.

```
127,102,0.732,1.23,10.5,0.27,2.58,999, 6 4 2 -2, [Ne]3s²3p, ORC,10.47
172.2,238.6, -,99, 0.477 (Cl-Cl), 6.41, 20.41 (Cl-Cl),0.009,3.16,1254.9, 7 5 3 1 -1, [Ne]3s²3p, ORC,6.24
87.3, -,98,0.138, -,6.52,0.0177,0,1519.6, -, [Ne]3s²3p, FCC,5.26
```

Данные значения я переношу в БД следующим образом:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
import csv
import psycopg2
import re

<...>

for row in file:
    row = re.sub(r'\([^\)]+\)', '', row)
    newrow = tuple(row.split(","))
    cur.execute('INSERT INTO table_element VALUES {};'.format(newrow))
    connection.commit()

<...>
```

В этом случае возникает проблема - в БД элемент [Ne]3s²3p² был переведен в 'Ne]3s\xc2\xb23p\xc2\xb2'

Да, его можно успешно вывести на экран в читаемом виде:

```
>>> print('[Ne]3s\xc2\xb23p\xc2\xb2'.decode('utf-8'))
[Ne]3s²3p²
```

но в БД он сохраняется кракозябрами.

Затем я решил сразу перейти в юникод:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
import csv
import psycopg2
import re

<...>


for row in file:
    row = unicode(row, 'utf-8')
    row = re.sub(r'\([^\)]+\)', '', row)
    newrow = tuple(row.replace(' ', '').split(","))
    cur.execute('INSERT INTO table_element VALUES {};'.format(newrow))
    connection.commit()

<...>
```

Однако при попытки выполнения возникает ошибка:

```
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: type "u" does not exist
LINE 1: INSERT INTO table_element VALUES (1, u'Hydrogen', u'H', u'1'...
```

Базу изначально создавал со следующими параметрами:

```
CREATE DATABASE data WITH ENCODING='UTF8' OWNER=postgres TEMPLATE=template0 LC_COLLATE='ru_RU.UTF-8' LC_CTYPE='ru_RU.UTF-8' CONNECTION LIMIT=-1 TABLESPACE=pg_default;
```

На каком варианте следует остановиться? И как сохранить данные в базе в человеческом виде?

Извлекаемые данные будут выводиться конечному пользователю и дальше обрабатываться.

Comment: Первый твой косяк в том что твои спец символы типа- ² , не могут быть представлены для ячеек в базе, в том виде в котором они есть. По сему следует для начала их конвертировать в более подобающий вид к примеру - hex, и уже потом именно хекс значение заносить в базу,  и потом считывать обратно(при запросе) .Посмотри документацию по своей базе, и конкретно по ячейкам, что они позволяют хранить, и в каком виде.

Comment: Да, спецсимволы все портят, и уход от первоначального вида тоже нежелателен. Для конечного пользователя я-то смогу преобразовать, но если будет необходимо поправить значение, будет неясно куда вносить изменения в непривычной кодировке

Comment: тогда проверьте вручную можно ли внести в те самые ячейки(базы) эти спец символы !

Comment: @LightFusion, как раз писал) Через админку джанго присвоил значение типа 1s¹. Оно корректно сохранилось и отобразилось в базе  .

Comment: почему тогда не разберете метод добавления в админке ?, или хоть по крайней мере скиньте в pastebin и добавите суда, чтобы можно было оценить как там устроенно.

Comment: это стандартная форма админки на основе модели. тут надо смотреть. если так получается, то значит можно через шелл конвертировать значение в поле и пересохранить в ячейку?

Comment: @LighFusion: Psycopg умеет с PostgreSQL обмениваться  Unicode—нет никакой необходимости какие-то свои схемы кодирования текста придумывать—`u'²'` символ (U+00B2) является обычным символом как и миллион других Unicode символов.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Чтобы импортировать сsv в PostgreSQL, используя код близкий к тому что показано в вопросе:

```
cur.executemany('INSERT INTO table VALUES({})'.format(','.join(['%s']*nfields)), [
    [field.decode('utf-8') if isinstance(field, str) else field
     for field in row] for row in csv_reader])
```

`csv` модуль на Питоне 2 не поддерживает Unicode поэтому явно приходится  байты (которые представляют текст, закодированный используя utf-8 кодировку) декодировать. Можно также готовый класс использовать, который скрывает эту конвертацию, например, [`UnicodeReader` из сsv документации](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#examples).

[Чтобы получать из базы данных назад также Unicode](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#unicode-handling):

```
import psycopg2
import psycopg2.extensions
psycopg2.extensions.register_type(psycopg2.extensions.UNICODE)
psycopg2.extensions.register_type(psycopg2.extensions.UNICODEARRAY)
```