# Как в python преобразовать u'\u041a\u043d\u0438\u0433\u0438' в нормальный вид?

Tags: python, парсер, scrapy

надо разобраться в ремесле парсинга) я только начинающий. Вопрос как преобразовать строку в нормальный вид

```
response.xpath("//a[@class='eCatalogLinks_Link']/text()).extract_first()
```

в ответ получаю

```
u'\u041a\u043d\u0438\u0433\u0438'
```

Comment: `print(u'\u041a\u043d\u0438\u0433\u0438')`

Comment: python 2 ветки?

Comment: https://habrahabr.ru/post/135913/

Comment: В чём у вас задача: напечатать текст в консоль? Сохранить его в файл? Передать по сети? Посмотрите [вторую половину ответа](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/521109/23044). Если вы не знаете как выглядят строковые  константы (unicode literals) в Питоне, то прочтите какое-нибудь вводное руководство, чтобы на базовых вещах не спотыкаться и не терять время.

Answer (score 1):

Всё довольно просто:

```
text = u'\u041a\u043d\u0438\u0433\u0438'
print(text)
```

И код выдаст слово:

```
Книги
```