# Реализация stdin и stdout

Tags: python, python-3.x, потоки-данных

В задаче (кроме самого алгоритма решения) необходимо реализовать прием данных через `stdin`, а вывод через `stdout`. До этого обычно реализовывал прием через `input`, а вывод через `print` или просто возвращал значение без печати через `return`. 
Как принять данные с помощью `stdin`/`stdout` не улавливаю. 
Огромная просьба, дать ссылку или пример кода, чтобы разобраться.

Comment: Это значит чтение и вывод в консоль а не в файл. Например print метод.

Comment: @pavel: stdin/stdout не обязаны на консоль указывать (это легко может быть файл, pipe или [даже (крайне редко) socket](https://gist.github.com/zed/7454768))

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

По умолчанию [`input()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input) читает данные из [`stdin`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.stdin), [`print()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print) печатает данные в [`stdout`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.stdin). Так что можете считать вашу задачу решённой.

В Питоне `stdin`, `stdout` представлены [`sys.stdin`, `sys.stdout`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.stdin) объектами ([текстовые потоки](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-file-object), как правило), которые в общем случае могут быть *любого типа* (если их интерфейс достаточно file-like) и могут быть переопределены *кем-угодно* (IDLE, bpython, ipython, IDE, win-unicode-console, etc). Иногда достаточно предоставить объект, который поддерживает единственный метод `.write()`, если нужно только `print()` функцию поддерживать. В других случаях, даже экземпляр [`io.TextIOWrapper`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.TextIOWrapper) (тип `sys.stdin`/`sys.stdout` по умолчанию) может быть недостаточным, если [`.fileno()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.IOBase.fileno) не возвращает настоящий file descriptor (см. детали в [Redirect stdout to a file in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22434262/4279)).

При запуске Питона, `sys.stdin`/`sys.stdout` обычно указывают на стандартные потоки ввода/вывода, унаследованные от родительского процесса или полученные от консоли. Интерактивный ввод/вывод как правило связан с терминалом. Из оболочки  легко перенаправить ввод/вывод из файла, канала (pipe)

```
$ python ваша-программа.py <входной-файл
# `sys.__stdin__` это входной-файл
$ echo abc | python ваша-программа.py
# `sys.__stdin__` это pipe (`echo` пишет с одного конца, мы читаем с другого)
```

Работа напрямую с `sys.stdin`, `sys.stdout` такая же как с другими текстовыми файлами. Например, чтобы прочитать текстовые строчки из *стандартного ввода* и записать введённые символы (Unicode codepoint) в каждой строке в обратном порядке в *стандартный вывод*:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import sys

for line in sys.stdin:
    print(line.rstrip('\n')[::-1])
```

Кодировка, используемая `sys.stdin`/`sys.stdout`, чтобы текст в байты превратить и обратно, может зависеть от окружения. Чтобы избежать [кракозяб](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/414060/23044) или `UnicodeEncodeError` исключения из-за [работы с произвольными Unicode символами в Windows консоль](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/141035/23044) и на [других платформах](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/387387/23044) следуйте по приведённым здесь ссылкам, которые показывают `win-unicode-console` ([PEP 528 возможно упразднит этот пакет](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32176732/4279)), `LC_*` (locale), `PYTHONIOENCODING` решения. [PEP-538, PEP-540 реализованные в Python 3.7](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.7.html#pep-538-legacy-c-locale-coercion) заставляют Питон использовать utf-8 в большем числе случаев, делая проблемы с кодировками ввода/вывода гораздо менее вероятными по умолчанию.

`print()` это удобный wrapper вокруг `sys.stdout.write()`. `input()`  часто можно рассматривать как wrapper вокруг `sys.stdin.readline()`, рассчитанный на интерактивный ввод (поддержка истории ввода, редактирования с помощью [`readline`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/readline.html) модуля, если доступен). Для продвинутой поддержки интерактивного ввода в терминале, посмотрите на [`prompt_toolkit`](https://github.com/jonathanslenders/python-prompt-toolkit#getting-started):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from prompt_toolkit import prompt # $ pip install prompt_toolkit

if __name__ == '__main__':
    answer = prompt('Give me some input: ')
    print('You said: %s' % answer)
```

Answer (score 5):

### `stdin` и `stdout` это файлоподобные объекты, предоставляемые OS.

*Для чтения и записи в них нужно импортнуть sys - `import sys`*.

**`sys.stdin.read()` использовать для чтения из `stdin`**

***для записи в `stdout` можно использовать `print`***(он так и используется - самый распространенный метод записи в stdout). т.е. `print` пишет в `sys.stdout`.

Пример:

```
import sys
str = sys.stdin.read()
print str
```

Comment: 1- `sys.stdin`/`stdout` не обязаны OS задаваться, например, `win-unicode-console` пакет может заменить их, чтобы работать с Unicode в Виндовой консоле.  2- `input()` сам по себе может из стандартного ввода читать, без явного использования `sys.stdin`. 3- я предполагаю, что автор использует Питон 3 (из-за использования `input()`, вместо `raw_input()`), поэтому `print()` должен быть функцией в примере.

Answer (score 0):

```
def countdistinctfivisors(n, start=2):
    if n == 1:
        return 1
    else:
        result = 0
        for i in range(start, n+1):
            if n % i == 0:
                result += countdistinctfivisors(n // i, i + 1)
        return result

print(countdistinctfivisors(int(input())))
```

Comment: Дайте пожалуйста пояснение к коду.  Пока не видно, как он отвечает на вопрос в этом топике.