# Как получить только что выведенную строку обратно в переменную?

Tags: python, python-3.x, print, exec

Я решил воспользоваться `exec()` для того, чтобы выполнять строки кода Python, получаемые на вход через `input()`. Но проблема `exec()` в мгновенном выводе строки, если я передаю в него `print('Hello')`, к примеру. Но мне не нужен вывод этой строки в консоль, а нужно записать её в переменную или массив, чтобы позже вывести данные через API или записать их в файл, допустим. Как это реализовать?

Я читал вопрос про [stdin/stdout](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/572737/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-stdin-%D0%B8-stdout), не стоит его упоминать. Там затрагивается другая тема, а ответчик на вопрос заявлет, что `print()` пишет в `sys.stdout`, однако это не так. Увы, `sys.stdout.readable()` возвращает мне False, а значит в любом случае я не смогу прочитать данные, которые попали туда через `print()`.

Жду ответа, спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In [53]: from io import StringIO

In [54]: from contextlib import redirect_stdout

In [55]: with StringIO() as buffer, redirect_stdout(buffer):
    ...:     print("hello world")
    ...:     out = buffer.getvalue()
    ...:

In [56]: out
Out[56]: 'hello world\n'
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, вы очень помогли мне!