# Отправка email. Не отправляется письмо с кириллицей

Tags: python, python-3.x, email, smtplib

Цель: Нужно отослать письмо на почту. В письме есть кириллические символы.

Проблема: скрипт работает с латинскими символами, но не работает с кириллицей

Скрипт:

```
import smtplib
TEXT = "Кириллица \n"\
        "Кириллица\n"

TO = 'xxxxxx@gmail.com'
SUBJECT = 'xxxx'
# Gmail Sign In
gmail_sender = 'xxxx@gmail.com'
gmail_passwd = 'xxxxxx'
server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
server.ehlo()
server.starttls()
server.login(gmail_sender, gmail_passwd)

BODY = '\r\n'.join(['To: %s' % TO,
                    'From: %s' % gmail_sender,
                    'Subject: %s' % SUBJECT,
                    '', TEXT])
try:
    server.sendmail(gmail_sender, [TO], BODY)
    print('email sent')
except:
    print('error sending mail')
server.quit()
```

Ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/babai/PycharmProjects/test/mail.py", line 47, in <module>
    server.sendmail(gmail_sender, [TO], BODY)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\smtplib.py", line 854, in sendmail
    msg = _fix_eols(msg).encode('ascii')
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 63-74: ordinal not in range(128)
```

На сколько я понимаю проблема в кодировке. Тоесть модуль smtplib работает только с ANSII ??

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Python 3.4 и русские символы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/387249/python-3-4-%d0%b8-%d1%80%d1%83%d1%81%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8b)

Comment: кириллица корректно выводится в консоль, думаю что проблема в другом

Comment: ааа, я понял MIMEText надо юзать

Comment: Используйте email модуль, чтобы текст письма в mime формате получить. См. [Кодировка при отправке сообщения](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/369427/23044)

Comment: Проблема решена. Использовал MIMEText.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Проблема решена с помощю MIMEText

Решение найдено вот здесь https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/369479/237582

Спасибо [jfs](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/23044/jfs)

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""Send email via smtp_host."""
import smtplib
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.header    import Header

smtp_host = 'smtp.gmail.com'  # yahoo
login = "xxxxxx@gmail.com"
password =  "xxxxxxx"
recipients_emails = "xxxxxx@gmail.com"

msg = MIMEText('Спасибо', 'plain', 'utf-8')
msg['Subject'] = Header('subject…', 'utf-8')
msg['From'] = login
msg['To'] = recipients_emails

s = smtplib.SMTP(smtp_host, 587, timeout=10)
s.set_debuglevel(1)
try:
    s.starttls()
    s.login(login, password)
    s.sendmail(msg['From'], recipients_emails, msg.as_string())
finally:
    print(msg)
    s.quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

[Тут посмотрите](https://bugs.python.org/issue25736) что нужно прописать:

```
# -*- coding: utf8 -*-
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Content-Disposition: inline
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
```

Comment: Дополните ответ, чтобы это было понятно куда именно это нужно прописать. Судя по первой строке это должно быть в python файле, но все что идет дальше не является валидным python кодом.