# Как отправить письмо на русском языке с помощью smtplib?

Tags: python, email, unicode, ascii, smtplib

Работаю с рассылкой сообщений по электронной почте, пользуюсь `smtplib`, а именно методом `sendmail`. Проблема заключается в том, что программа выдает ошибку:

> builtins.UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in
>   position 0-4: ordinal not in range(128)

Если в сообщении есть символы, которых нет в `ASCII`(видимо), например, русские буквы.

Как это исправить? Есть ли вообще какой-то способ отправить электронное сообщение из русских символов?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/694146/201445

Comment: @gil9red дубликат?

Comment: @andreymal, да, предлагаю вопрос закрыть. СергейЛоптев ваш вопрос уже имеет решение, поэтому предлагаю закрыть его как дубликат