# Qt5 отладчик выдаёт нечитаемый текст

Tags: qt, ubuntu, qt5, qtcreator

Ubuntu 16.04 x64, qt 5.1, qtcreator 3.5.1
Как сделать (кракозябры) текст читаемым?

```
Отладка запущена
&"warning: GDB: Failed to set controlling terminal: \320\235\320\265\320\277\321\200\320\270\320\274\320\265\320\275\320\270\320\274\321\213\320\271 \320\272 \320\264\320\260\320\275\320\275\320\276\320\274\321\203 \321\203\321\201\321\202\321\200\320\276\320\271\321\201\321\202\320\262\321\203 ioctl\n"
&"Cannot exec  -c exec /media/bigdata/home/alexandr1/Qt/program/progQT/SmtpClient-for-Qt-1.1/demos/build-demo2-5_6-Debug/demo2 .\n"
&"Error: \320\235\320\265\321\202 \321\202\320\260\320\272\320\276\320\263\320\276 \321\204\320\260\320\271\320\273\320\260 \320\270\320\273\320\270 \320\272\320\260\321\202\320\260\320\273\320\276\320\263\320\260\n"
Отладка завершена
```

В консоле:

```
locale
LANG=ru_RU.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=ru
LC_CTYPE="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC=ru_RU.UTF-8
LC_TIME=ru_RU.UTF-8
LC_COLLATE="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY=ru_RU.UTF-8
LC_MESSAGES="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER=ru_RU.UTF-8
LC_NAME=ru_RU.UTF-8
LC_ADDRESS=ru_RU.UTF-8
LC_TELEPHONE=ru_RU.UTF-8
LC_MEASUREMENT=ru_RU.UTF-8
LC_IDENTIFICATION=ru_RU.UTF-8
LC_ALL=
```

**UPD 2:**

при запуске через консоль:

```
LC_ALL=C qtcreator
```

выдаёт:

```
Отладка запущена
&"warning: GDB: Failed to set controlling terminal: Inappropriate ioctl for device\n"
&"Cannot exec  -c exec /media/bigdata/home/alexandr1/Qt/program/progQT/SmtpClient-for-Qt-1.1/demos/build-demo2-5_6-Debug/demo2 .\n"
&"Error: No such file or directory\n"
Отладка завершена
```

в коде:

```
qDebug() << QLocale::c();
```

выдаёт (не важно как был запущен Qt):

```
C QLocale(C, Default, Default)
```

Comment: попробуйте запустить qt-creator  с консоли вот так `LC_ALL=C qtcreator`

Comment: @KoVadim таким образом отладка работает, что исправить в дефолтной загрузке приложения?

Comment: если вы хотите сообщения об ошибках на английском получать, то можно `LANG=C.UTF-8` выставить в `.profile` или индивидуально для приложения. См. [Не сохраняются переменные XUBUNTU](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/386629/23044)

Comment: @jfs LANG не выделяется как зарезервированное слово, результат отладчик сообщает о тех же проблемах

Comment: Нажмите на ссылку в моём комментарии. LANG это переменная окружения. Приведите вывод команды `locale` (в bash запускайте, не в отладчике)

Comment: @jfs изменил locale LANG=C.UTF-8, результат тот же

Comment: Поиск в таком порядке происходит: [LANGUAGE, LC_ALL, LC_xxx (LC_MESSAGES/LC_CTYPE), LANG](https://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/html_node/Locale-Environment-Variables.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Изменил строку запуска в ярлыке. Замечу, что смена языка в самом qtcreator не приводит к положительному результату.

```
sudo nano /usr/share/applications/qtcreator.desktop 

[Desktop Entry]
Exec=env LC_ALL=C qtcreator %F
Icon=QtProject-qtcreator
Type=Application
Terminal=false
Name=Qt Creator
GenericName=Integrated Development Environment
MimeType=text/x-c++src;text/x-c++hdr;text/x-xsrc;application/x-designer;application/vnd.nokia.qt.qmakeprofile;application/vnd.nokia.xml.qt.resource;
Categories=Qt;Development;IDE;
InitialPreference=9
```