# Сменить локаль Ubuntu 16.04 x64

Tags: linux, ubuntu, locale

После некоторых манипуляций с системой интерфейс ОС стал на английском, как и все запускаемые по умолчанию приложения. Пробовал изменить локаль через ГУИ, однако там всё на местах.

```
locale
LANG=ru_RU.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=C.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=ru_RU.UTF-8

locale -a
C
C.UTF-8
en_AG
en_AG.utf8
en_AU.utf8
en_BW.utf8
en_CA.utf8
en_DK.utf8
en_GB.utf8
en_HK.utf8
en_IE.utf8
en_IN
en_IN.utf8
en_NG
en_NG.utf8
en_NZ.utf8
en_PH.utf8
en_SG.utf8
en_US.utf8
en_ZA.utf8
en_ZM
en_ZM.utf8
en_ZW.utf8
POSIX
ru_RU.utf8
ru_UA.utf8

cat /etc/default/locale 
#  File generated by update-locale
LANG="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LANGUAGE="ru:en"
LC_NUMERIC="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="ru_RU.UTF-8"

nano ~/.bashrc
# ~/.bashrc: executed by bash(1) for non-login shells.
# see /usr/share/doc/bash/examples/startup-files (in the package bash-doc)
# for examples
#export LC_xxx=C.UTF-8
export LC_ALL=ru_RU.UTF-8
...

cat /proc/$(pgrep -u $(whoami) | head -n 1)/environ | xargs -0 -n 1 echo | grep '^\(LANG\|LC\)'
LANG=ru_RU.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=ru:en
LC_ADDRESS=ru_RU.UTF-8
LC_IDENTIFICATION=ru_RU.UTF-8
LC_MEASUREMENT=ru_RU.UTF-8
LC_MONETARY=ru_RU.UTF-8
LC_NAME=ru_RU.UTF-8
LC_NUMERIC=ru_RU.UTF-8
LC_PAPER=ru_RU.UTF-8
LC_TELEPHONE=ru_RU.UTF-8
LC_TIME=ru_RU.UTF-8

localectl
   System Locale: LANG=ru_RU.UTF-8
                  LANGUAGE=ru:en
       VC Keymap: n/a
      X11 Layout: us,ru
       X11 Model: pc105
     X11 Variant: ,
     X11 Options: grp:alt_shift_toggle,grp_led:scroll
```

поскольку gdb в консоли пишет по русски выполнил команду с его PID:

```
cat /proc/4274/environ 2>/dev/null | xargs -0 -n 1 echo | grep '^\(LANG\|LC\)'
LC_PAPER=ru_RU.UTF-8
LC_ADDRESS=ru_RU.UTF-8
LC_MONETARY=ru_RU.UTF-8
LC_NUMERIC=ru_RU.UTF-8
LC_TELEPHONE=ru_RU.UTF-8
LC_IDENTIFICATION=ru_RU.UTF-8
LANG=ru_RU.UTF-8
LC_MEASUREMENT=ru_RU.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=ru
LC_TIME=ru_RU.UTF-8
LC_NAME=ru_RU.UTF-8
```

по английски:

Xorg

```
cat /proc/1257/environ 2>/dev/null | xargs -0 -n 1 echo | grep '^\(LANG\|LC\)'
```

yandex_browser

```
cat /proc/2642/environ 2>/dev/null | xargs -0 -n 1 echo | grep '^\(LANG\|LC\)'
```

**UPD:1**

```
env | grep '^\(LANG\|LC\)' 
LC_PAPER=ru_RU.UTF-8
LC_ADDRESS=ru_RU.UTF-8
LC_MONETARY=ru_RU.UTF-8
LC_NUMERIC=ru_RU.UTF-8
LC_TELEPHONE=ru_RU.UTF-8
LC_IDENTIFICATION=ru_RU.UTF-8
LANG=ru_RU.UTF-8
LC_MEASUREMENT=ru_RU.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=ru
LC_TIME=ru_RU.UTF-8
LC_NAME=ru_RU.UTF-8

sudo nano /etc/X11/Xsession.d/00upstart
```

**UPD: 2**

добавил строку:

```
env | grep '^\(LANG\|LC\)' >> /tmp/log.file
```

презапустил сессию

```
cat /tmp/log.file 
LC_PAPER=ru_RU.UTF-8
LC_ADDRESS=ru_RU.UTF-8
LC_MONETARY=ru_RU.UTF-8
LC_NUMERIC=ru_RU.UTF-8
LC_TELEPHONE=ru_RU.UTF-8
LC_IDENTIFICATION=ru_RU.UTF-8
LANG=ru_RU.UTF-8
LC_MEASUREMENT=ru_RU.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=C.UTF-8
LC_TIME=ru_RU.UTF-8
LC_NAME=ru_RU.UTF-8
```

Comment: `LANGUAGE=C.UTF-8` → `LANGUAGE=ru`

Comment: какое вообще отношение файл `.bashrc` может к вашей x-сессии? для начала удостоверьтесь, что запущенные от вашего имени программы получают корректные значения:  `for p in $(pgrep -u $(whoami)); do cat /proc/$p/environ 2>/dev/null | xargs -0 -n 1 echo | grep '^\(LANG\|LC\)'; done | sort -u`

Comment: Уж сколько раз твердили миру, что локаль — это свойство приложения, а не системы.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin делал это https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/723433/qt5-отладчик-выдаёт-нечитаемый-текст сейчас произвёл обратные шаги, но результат пока не изменился

Comment: вы про какие «шаги»? изменение содержимого desktop-файла? это уж никак не может повлиять на язык интерфейса. так переменные окружения какого-нибудь «не по-русски пишущего» процесса проверили? `$ cat /proc/идентификатор-процесса/environ 2>/dev/null | xargs -0 -n 1 echo | grep '^\(LANG\|LC\)'`

Comment: не поняли. объясняю. в каталоге `/etc/X11/Xsession.d/` находятся скрипты, которые запускаются при старте x-сессии. в том порядке, в котором их выдаёт, например, программа *ls*: обычно в начале их имён стоят цифры. вот эти цифры и определяют последовательность запуска. добавьте в начало самого первого скрипта команду, которую я привёл в пред. комментарии, перезапустите x-сессию («разлогиньтесь/залогиньтесь») и смотрите, что попадёт в файл `/tmp/log.file`. в зависимости от того, будут ли там присутствовать определённые в `/etc/default/locale` переменные, можно будет сделать какие-то выводы.

Comment: related [How to change system language?](https://askubuntu.com/q/289190/3712)

Comment: как видите, [переменная LANGUAGE](https://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/html_node/The-LANGUAGE-variable.html) имеет совсем не то значение, которое вам хотелось бы. ищите, где она переопределяется. а заодно — где вообще убираются из окружения процессов переменные окружения, имена которых начинаются на `LANG` или `LC`. удачи!

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67654/discussion-on-question-by-shaman888---ubuntu-16-04-x64).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

поиск файла и строки с заданной настройкой (см. вопрос)

```
grep -r "LANGUAGE=C.UTF-8" /home/
```

найденный файл оказался .profile

```
nano .profile
```

комментирую строку

```
#export LANGUAGE=C.UTF-8
```

Забыл что там производил изменения и сам файл как то скрывался с глаз. За решение выражаю благодарность  "alexander barakin"