# Запуск bash-скрипта при открытии нового окна терминала в Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ubuntu, bash

Доброго времени суток!

Написал небольшой bash-скрипт, использующий команду `cowsay`:

```
# !/bin/bush

namesOfSpeakers=(bong beavis.zen bud-frogs dragon-and-cow duck elephant elephant-in-snake ghostbusters koala mech-and-cow moofasa stegosaurus turtle tux)

SPOTS=${#namesOfSpeakers[@]}
number=$RANDOM
let "number %= $SPOTS"

fortune | cowsay -f ${namesOfSpeakers[$number]}
```

Скрипт работает корректно, но я хотел бы сделать так, чтобы данный скрипт запускался при КАЖДОМ открытии нового окна терминала. Несколько часов поиска в гугле не помогли. Надеюсь на помощь сообщества.

OS: Ubuntu 16.04

P.S. Это не имеет особого отношения к вопросу, но если кому интересно, опишу подробнее принцип работы скрипта.

Команда `cowsay [текст]` из пакета "cowsay" выводит небольшой комикс с коровой, говорящей [**текст**].
Команду `cowsay` можно выполнить с параметром так, чтобы вместо коровы было другое животное, например: 
`cowsay -f dragon "Привет!"`

[image: пример работы команды cowsay с параметром -f dragon]

Команда `fortune` из пакета fortune выдаёт случайную цитату на английском языке. Русские цитаты были установлены командой:

```
sudo apt-get install fortunes fortune-mod fortunes-min fortunes-ru
```

Понятно, что `fortune` и `cowsay` - не связанные друг с другом команды, но их можно объединить так, чтобы персонажи из `cowsay` выдавали цитату из `fortune`

```
fortune | cowsay -f stegosaurus
```

[image: пример совмещения cowsay и fortune]

В своём скрипте я добавил в массив названия понравившихся мне живых существ, и при запуске скрипта случайное животное из массива `namesOfSpeakers` "говорит" какую-либо цитату из `fortune`

[image: пример работы скрипта]

Comment: в `~/.bashrc` просто добавь...

Comment: в сторону: shebang исправьте (две ошибки)

Comment: @Fat-Zer: `~/.bashrc` может и для не login, не interactive случая использоваться. См.  [Не сохраняются переменные XUBUNTU](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/386629/23044)

Comment: @jfs, дык, как я понял ТСу и нужен грейтер для иксовых терминалов (это интерактивный не-логин шелл)... и когда он может для не-интерактивного случая выполняться (на адекватно сконфигурированной системе)?

Comment: @Fat-Zer, огромное спасибо! Добавил вызов скрипта в конец файла  .bashrc и всё заработало!)

Comment: @Fat-Zer: верно, у автора non-login, interactive случай, я  как вариант изменения motd воспринял (иначе это быстро надоест)¶ Слова "адекватно сконфигурированы" я бы не стал к [подобным диаграммам применять](https://blog.flowblok.id.au/2013-02/shell-startup-scripts.html) (из .profile может если существует .bashrc запускаться)

Comment: @jfs, мда... там правда подводные камни с remote shell'ом идут... причём в пакетном режиме по ssh'у он выполняется, а в обычном — нет... у меня были опасения, что где-то как-то на это можно будет напороться, но пробежав глазами по `man bash` я сначала  успокоился...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Хочу сказать огромное спасибо пользователю @Fat-Zer за его комментарий под моим вопросом. Именно благодаря ему всё решилось.

Итак, всё оказалось гораздо проще, чем я думал. В Linux Ubuntu, в домашней папке, по адресу: **home/[имя_пользователя]** (в моём случае - **/home/artur**) располагается скрытый файл (показ скрытых файлов - **Ctrl+H**) **.bashrc**

Этот файл определяет поведение командной оболочки bash, а, в частности, определяет команды, выполняемые при открытии терминала. Сам я новичок в Linux, поэтому, чтобы не наговорить глупостей, не буду описывать подробнее, скажу лишь, что мой скрипт с названием **script2**, находится по адресу **./Scripts/**, и простой вызов данного скрипта...

```
./Scripts/script2
```

... добавленный в самый конец файла **.bashrc**, приводит к тому, что при каждом запуске терминала происходит выполнение написанного мною скрипта. А это именно то, чего я хотел добиться!

P.S. Данный способ не рекомендуется, если Вы знаете, что к Вашему устройству будут подключаться по ssh.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Добавлю, что всё же пользоваться этим стоит с осторожностью: это может поломать некоторые специфические скрипты и методы работы, например команды типа `ssh <host> cat /some/file >/some/file` (один из способов удалённого копирования через ssh).

Comment: @Fat-Zer, я правильно понимаю, что если я попытаюсь связаться с удалённым сервером через ssh (скажем, с помощью приложения filezilla), то у меня возникнут проблемы? А если я через команды в терминале буду подключаться к удалённому серверу, также с ОС Ubuntu, по ssh?

Comment: нет, проблемы могут возникнуть если связываться **с текущим хостом**, на котором это настроено... случайно напороться на это не так просто, но можно, а специально можно сделать например `ssh localhost ls /` и окромя содержимого корня полюбоваться на черепашку... в скрипте подобное будет фатально... sftp/scp этому не должны быть подвержен — там оболочка не запускается...

Comment: Дабы избежать этого я бы предложил сохранить графическую часть куда-нибудь в `.my_terminal_bashrc` (в конце не забыв дописать `source ~/.bashrc`), а в настройках терминала прописать запуск оболочки `bash --rcfile ~/.my_terminal_bashrc`